# Interpolação de Lagrange - ERRO no [do while]

Tags: java

Estou criando um método para pegar **n** valores, adicionando-os em um array, e desses valores aplicar o método de interpolação de Lagrange para encontrar um polinômio. Logo após, encontrar um valor estimado de **x** para o intervalo definido pelo maior e o menor valor do conjunto de dados inputados.

Só que está dando um erro no **do while**, pois ele até pega o primeiro valor, mas ao passar pela primeira instrução de input ele dá o seguinte:

- ERRO:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

at lagrange.calculate(lagrange.java:13)

at Main.main(Main.java:6)

exit status 1

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lagrange{
   public void calculate(){
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      double n[];
      int cont = 0;

      do {
        n = new double[cont];
        System.out.println("Digite o valor de numero " + cont + 1);
        n[cont] = sc.nextDouble(); //INPUT DE DADO NO ARRAY
        cont = cont + 1;
      } while(n[cont - 1] != 0); //continuar o processo até o array for igual a zero

   System.out.println(n[cont-1]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na linha

```
int cont = 0;
```

troque para

```
System.out.println("Digite o grau do polinômio");
int cont = sc.nextInt() + 1;
int indice = 0;
```

Na linha

```
System.out.println("Digite o valor de numero " + cont + 1);
```

troque para

```
System.out.println("Digite o valor do coeficiente " + indice);
```

Na linha

```
n[cont] = sc.nextDouble();
```

troque para

```
n[indice] = sc.nextDouble();
```

Retire a linha

```
cont = cont + 1;
```

Na linha

```
} while (n[cont - 1] != 0);
```

troque para

```
} while (n[indice++] != 0 && indice < cont);
```